# Seg Fault in function getData

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

My program is supposed to read through files and collect and store data which i have stored into a single string fileContents. getData is supposed to return the next integer in the string and change a char* to the proper command, i or d, for insert or delete respectively. Here's the code below.

```
int getData(const char* fileContents, char* command)
{
  char* chardata = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if (*command == 0) // if first data
    charData = strtok((char*) fileContents, " ");
  cout << charData << "\n"; // output
  *command = charData[0];
  return atoi(charData + 1);
} // end getData
```

The function runs perfectly for the first 37300 data entries but I keep getting a Segmentation Fault on 37301. Any help is appreciated.

Data in the file is in the format i1 i2 i3 ... i250000 and is in the same form in fileContents.

My output on calling this function is 
i1
i2
i3
...
i37299
i37300
i3730
Seg Fault

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/). We can't do much with this code.

Comment: Perhaps including a sample of good vs bad data might help?

Comment: Run it in a debugger.  You might be going past the end of the read in `fileContents`.  Since `strtok` will modify its first parameter, `getData` should not take `fileContents` as a `const char *`.